# how to get a value out of a cell into a userform vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use a value of my active worksheet to put in a userform. This has to be dynamic because in my worksheet i have multiple values.
The userform open hisself if you click on a button using a macro.

Here are the pictures of the values that i want to put automatically in my userfrom and also my userform.

Thanx

[image: This the worksheet with the values]

[enter image description here][2]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq8cQ.png)

Comment: Which row of data do you want to display in the userform?

Comment: all of them every time in an other textbox

Comment: Is the form being displayed as modeless? Do you wish to show the row that is currently selected in the worksheet and then update the userform when the selection changes?

Answer (score 0):

In your worksheet (asuming your userform is named UserForm1).
Change [your column] to the column number you want to autofire your macro.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If UserForm1.Visible And Target.Column = [your column] Then
    call UserForm1.GetCellText(Target.Row)
  End If
End Sub
```

In your Userform (asuming your textboxes are named TextBox1, TextBox2...).

```
Sub GetCellText(xRow As Integer)
  Dim i As Byte
  For i = 1 To 7
    Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value = Cells(xRow, i)
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: i tested it... and it worked. can you tell me where the error comes from? (are all names correct?)

Comment: ok change `call UserForm1.GetCellText(Target.Row)` and your column [A] to 1 that should do it... forgot the ()... sorry